# Property "secure" getting ignored in textfield

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript

I am currently working on some tests in nativescript/vuejs just to see how it works and if I can work with it.

After one hour of work I already got a problem which I thought would be good to ask on stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a simple login screen using two Textfields and one button.
One textfield has to be secured or "hidden" since you need to fill in your password there.

In the documentation found here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/text-field/
you can see that the property secure is made specifically for this task.

But after adding secure="true" to my textfield nothing happened...

XML:

```
    <StackLayout class="body" row="0">
        <TextView :hint="usernameHint" editable="true" class="username-textview" v-model="username"/>
        <TextView secure="true" :hint="passwordHint" editable="true" v-model="password"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit-button" @tap="onSubmitButtonPressed" :text="submitText"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

As you can see on the result below nothing happens...

[image]

What could be the cause and how should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think secure is accessible if you use TextField not TextView.